# F# Recursively creating a int list list

Tags: list, recursion, f#, tail-recursion

So I have a bitmap which is an int list list, 3 indexes per pixel representing rgb.
One row of the image is one list, and I'm trying to recursively edit this int list list and spit back another int list list. The problem is when I reach the end of a row I want it to create another list. Right now the code creates one pixel per row aka 3 values per list and makes the image a line going straight down, so it's creating a new list each recursive call. I want it to continue on that same list while it hasn't reached the end of the width. Here's the code to make a bit more sense because I'm having a hard time explaining it.

```
let rec GrayscaleImage(width:int, widthVar:int, image:int list list) =
    match image with
    |[] -> []
    |_ -> let r = image.Head.Head 
          let g = image.Head.Tail.Head
          let b = image.Head.Tail.Tail.Head
          let average = (int)((r+g+b)/3) 
          if widthVar > 3 then [average; average; average] :: GrayscaleImage(width, widthVar - 1, image.Tail.Tail.Tail)
          else ???
```

Firstly after the if then it will create a new list, I want it to continue that list of averages.(it's grayscaling the image btw) Then in the else I know that it should do something like it does on the if, but probably not exactly. I'm just extremely confused on how to go about doing this. Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I made some progress with this following code

```
let rec BuildRowGrayscale(cols:int, a:int) =
    match cols with
    |0 -> []
    |_ -> a :: a :: a :: BuildRowGrayscale (cols-1) a

let rec GrayscaleImage(width:int, height:int, depth:int, image:int list list) =
    match image with
    |[] -> []
    |_ -> 
          let r = image.Head.Head
          let g = image.Head.Tail.Head
          let b = image.Head.Tail.Tail.Head
          let avg = (int)((r+g+b)/3)
          (BuildRowGrayscale width avg) :: GrayscaleImage(width, height, depth, image.Tail)
```

But it refuses to compile at `(BuildRowGrayscale width avg)` and `BuildRowGrayscale (cols-1)` saying 
"This value is not a function and cannot be applied"

Comment: just a tip - avoid using `.Head` and `.tail` I would change your `|_ -> ` to `|r::g::b::rest`

Comment: If you want to create a new list when you reach the end of the row your result would be an int list list list

Comment: For update do `BuildRowGrayscale (width,avg)` and `BuildRowGrayscale (cols-1,a)` (you have used tuple form in definition.

Comment: BuildRowGrayscale takes a `Tuple<int,int>` while you're passing it `int` and `int` as if its type signature was `int->int->int list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your comment, I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
let rec GrayscaleImage image =
    let rec BuildRowGrayscale = 
        function
        | [] -> []
        | r::g::b::rest -> 
            let avg = (r+g+b)/3
            (avg :: avg :: avg :: BuildRowGrayscale rest)
        | _ -> failwith "Invalid image"
    match image with
    | []        -> []
    | row::rest -> BuildRowGrayscale row :: GrayscaleImage rest
```

Or using `List.replicate` and `List.map`:

```
let GrayscaleImage =
    let rec BuildRowGrayscale = function
        | []            -> []
        | r::g::b::rest -> List.replicate 3 ((r+g+b)/3) @ BuildRowGrayscale rest
        | _             -> failwith "Invalid image"
    List.map BuildRowGrayscale
```

Sorry, but the fact you were specifying a width made me think you were changing the original structure as well, but if the structure doesn't change you don't need to specify a width, it's implicit in the original structure.

Comment: Thank you very much all this code helped me quite a lot understand how to go about doing this the only misunderstanding is that you did this thinking the structure was as such

[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[5,10,255]] etc
instead it's like [1,1,1,2,2,2,5,10,255] with the next list representing the row down from it so each list is one horizontal pixel row for the image. Currently the code doesn't work because of this I think I can make it work though, though I really have a hard time with F#. I'm definitely more of an OO programmer, I'd even much rather do C than F# personally haha.

Comment: Oh, if the structure doesn't change then you don't need to specify the width. You just need to grayScale. See the update.

Comment: You're welcome. In exchange you show me how to grayscale, I didn't know it was just an r g b average. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming `image` contains the pixels for you image. Since you are only doing a pixel-wise operation you just need to map the outer list.

```
let GrayscaleImage =
    let avg = function
        | r::g::b::_ ->
            let average = (r+g+b)/3
            [average; average; average]
        | _ -> failwith "expected 3 colors"
    List.map avg
```

Comment: This won't quite work properly as what was `g` the previous iteration will become `r` on the next iteration, which I don't think is what he wants.

Comment: This does not compile as it returns a list of a list of a list.. etc, not sure how many the error is quite long, but I can see how this method of approach would work I'm just having a hard time making it compile as the function must return an int list list

Comment: @Man It compiles for me: val GrayscaleImage : (int list list -> int list list)

Comment: @John  What iteration? No recursion involved.

Comment: iteration with `List.map`